# ZXing.Mobile.Net.Forms ZXing.Result Type Issue

Tags: xamarin, zxing.net

I'm trying to get the result of a scan using a `MobileBarcodeScanner`.  If I save the result as a `var` everything works fine, but as soon as I try to use `ZXing.Result`, I get the message `The type 'Result' exists in both 'zxing, Version=0.16.5.0 ...' and 'zxing.portable, Version=0.16.2.0 ...'`

I have these packages installed:

- ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version 2.4.1
- ZXing.Net.Mobile, Version 2.4.1
- Zxing.Net, Version 0.16.5

I've seen other people use `ZXing.Result`, do I have an extra package installed? Am I missing one?  Is there a way to mitigate this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `ZXing.Net` seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Though removing Zxing.Net may work, but it could cause some issues when you release your project.

The proper solution should be:
- Look at the dependency of ZXing.Net.Mobile for the exact version it's using Zxing.Net.
- Install that version, there is a high chance that ZXing.net 0.16.5 is lower than the version it's expecting.

Comment: It looks like ZXing.Net.Mobile doesn't have any dependencies, and ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms only Depends on ZXing.Net.Mobile. It seems like ZXing.Net.Mobile already has ZXing.Net?  I thought I had seen though that it was required, but I've had no problems so far.